# Image not updating when read from metro application's local folder

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-8.1

I am displaying an image from my application's local folder in my metro application developed using Html/WinJS.

```
 app.onactivated = function (args) {
 document.getElementById('img').src = "ms-appdata:///local/test.jpg";
}
```

what i am doing is editing the image in some other application and getting it reloaded again on button click

```
function update() {
document.getElementById('img').src = "ms-appdata:///local/test.jpg";
}
```

but the image is not getting updated. It gets updated only after app relaunch.

Does  "ms-appdata:///local/" cache data and refreshes only on app relaunch ?
Or where i am going wrong, kindly suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that setting img.src to the same value as before won't trigger a reload, and the rendering engine won't automatically update the image based on file changes. One trick you can try is to attach a ?foo= parameter on the URI, incrementing  each time to effectively change the URI and triggering a reload.

Alternately, open the file using [StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefromapplicationuriasync.aspx)(new Windows.Foundation.Uri()). Then you can pass the StorageFile to URL.createObjectURL, and assign the result to the img.src. That should completely refresh the image.

Note that for consumption purposes where you don't need to load all the pixels (as you would for editing) it's best to get a thumbnail from StorageFile.[getThumbnailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getthumbnailasync.aspx) (or [getScaledImageAsThumbnailAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.getscaledimageasthumbnailasync.aspx) on Windows 8.1) and pass that result to URL.createObjectURL instead. This will avoid loading the whole image, especially for smaller display sizes, thus lowering your memory overhead and increasing performance.